# Merging two versions of a project with git

Tags: git, merge, repository

Consider the following scenario. There're two git repos, representing two versions of project P. Repo A has P v0.1 with some custom patches and repo B has P v0.2 without these patches. How to merge patches from A into repo B, using git? Or is it better to just manually check which files were modified and "import" patches by manually diffing all changed files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beautiful thing in git is that a repo is a just repo, so you can pull a repo A branch from repo B just as if you did it from a remote

```
git remote add repoA /path/to/repoA/.git
git pull repoA
```

That's assuming they are on same filesystem. If they aren't you need to use some protocol. Probably easiest way is to

```
repoA
--------
git daemon --base-path=path/to/one/dir/above/repoA --export-all

repoB
--------
git remote add repoA git://<repoA_IP>/repoA
git pull repoA

repoA
--------
shutdown daemon(Ctrl+C)
```

You need to enable traffic on port 9418. 
Unfortunately you may get various errors running it under windows, but at least some are fixable - you need to consult google for details.

Comment: yeah, sure, but it was more about what can you do with git ;)

Comment: yes, exactly.  my point is that you don't need a network connection.  since a repo is just a repo, just copy repoA to the machine with repoB, then use the solution from the first four lines of your answer.